# getimagesize and $_FILES in php

Tags: php, file-upload

i know there is a lot of question in this topic, i tried almost every one procedure but my issue is still same...

**Problem is**
i am trying to upload an image file and want to get image height and image width, i search a lot and find that getimagesize will do it, but when i try this code

```
$file=$_FILES['myfile'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
$file_width=$width;
$file_height=$height;
```

then this error is shown..

```
Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

After this error i search more about that function and the i try this code....

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    $file_width=$width;
    $file_height=$height;
```

after executing the code nothing would happen...

** Update** Actually i am trying to get the image height and width and save the information in database. So i want that when user upload picture then before saving the information i get the height and width of image file and the other thing is that image source would be any this like from usp or memory card, so don't say me that to pass the full path as parameter in `getimagesize()`. Kindly provide me proper solution, if there is any other way to get the file height and width then refer me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to upload file then pass the uploaded location

```
getimagesize("location_of_file/".$file_name);
```

OR

```
getimagesize($path['path'].'/'.$_POST['name']);
```

OR

```
$file_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
getimagesize($target_dir.'/'.$file_name);
```

OR

```
$file_tmp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);
     $file_width=$width;
     $file_height=$height;
```

Comment: `$_FILES['myfile']['name']` contains the name from the local machine. `$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']` contains the uploaded file path.

Comment: Probably won't work because of php stores the path and filename in the tmp_name array element and name is just the original filename on the uploader's disk.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. After you have completed the file upload, everything should be fine.

```
  $temporary_name = $file['painting_picture']['tmp_name'];

    if (is_uploaded_file($temporary_name)) {
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($temporary_name); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not do anything with your data. Try to `echo` it:

```
if (isset($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    list($file_width, $file_height) = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    echo "The file dimensions is: width ".$file_width."px, height: ". $file_height."px";
}
```